# Summary in Crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

In Segate Crystal Report how to add the summary ie. @ last page I need total number of pages and number of records in respective page and total Balance Amount of that respective page.Please help me out to solve this problem.
Example:-
Pages       No of accounts                            TotalBalance.
Page 1         38                                     42000.00
page 2         40(Excluding page 1 Records)           12000.00(Exclud page1 Records)
Page 3         30(Excluding page1,2 Records)          10000.00(Exclud page1,2 Records)
:
:
:
So on 
Thanks,
Karthik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an attempt at trying to do this with Formula Fields...

### Step 1 - Create Formula Field to reset the total on each new page.

Create a new Formula Field to reset the page totals add this to the Page Header section. Call the field *ResetOnNewPage* and add the following formula (in Crystal Syntax)

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
Global NumberVar PageTotal := 0;
Global NumberVar RowCount := 0;
```

Add this to the *Page Header* section and hide it by ticking *Suppress* in the Format Editor

### Step 2 - Create a Formula Field to perform the running total.

Create a new Formula Field called CalculateOnEachDetail and add the following formula

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
Global NumberVar PageTotal;
Global NumberVar RowCount;
PageTotal := PageTotal + {Command.s};
RowCount := RowCount + 1;
```

**Note:** You'll need to change the bit in the curly braces to reflect your table/Fieldname. (*I used a command with a single field called 's'*)

Add this to the *Detail* section and again hide it in the *Format Editor*

### Step 3 - Create a Formula Field for each of the two values we are calculating

Create one formula field called *ShowPageTotal* with the following formula

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
Global NumberVar PageTotal;
PageTotal;
```

And one formula field called *ShowRowCount* with the this formula

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
Global NumberVar RowCount;
RowCount;
```

Drop this on the page footer and Bob's your uncle!

Comment: Thanx for ur replie but i need @ last page as summary ie., page1  has these many records page2 has these many records I don't want in individual pages, how to do it.

Comment: Oh I see...! now I understand the question!

Comment: Hi @Dogears, I have a very similar problem with regards to your answer, I used almost the same code of yours, the only difference My report contains a grouping so, I put the formulas 1 and 3 in group header and footer respective, it is working well but not with a one group report with two pages, It is not getting the values from the previous page. How can we handle that situation?

Answer (score 0):

Crystal Reports doesn't "think" in terms of pages. It thinks in terms of records and groups.  As such, there is no function that says "For all records on this page, add this number". There are ways around this limitation, but they'll take some time for you to understand & develop.

The first method I can think of is to structure your report so that the same number of records appear on each page.  For example, if exactly 10 records appeared on each page, then you can make a running total to add 10 records at a time and then reset.

The second method would involve getting creative with making a custom grouping variable and only showing 1 group per page.